# Regression Analysis with statsmodels in Python

Tags: python, statsmodels

I'm new to Python and learning how to do regression analysis with `statsmodels` in Python (moving from R to Python and thinking in R ways). My minimum working example is below:

```
Income  =  [80, 100, 120, 140, 160, 180, 200, 220, 240, 260]
Expend  =  [70,  65,  90,  95, 110, 115, 120, 140, 155, 150]

import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
{'Income': Income,
     'Expend': Expend
    })

#regression with formula
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf

#instantiation
reg1 = smf.ols('Expend ~ Income', data = df1)

#members of reg object
print(dir(reg1))

['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_data_attr', '_df_model', '_df_resid', '_fit_ridge', '_get_init_kwds', '_handle_data', '_init_keys', '_setup_score_hess', 'data', 'df_model', 'df_resid', 'endog', 'endog_names', 'exog', 'exog_names', 'fit', 'fit_regularized', 'formula', 'from_formula', 'get_distribution', 'hessian', 'information', 'initialize', 'k_constant', 'loglike', 'nobs', 'predict', 'rank', 'score', 'weights', 'wendog', 'wexog', 'whiten']

#members of the object provided by the modelling.
print(dir(reg1.fit()))

['HC0_se', 'HC1_se', 'HC2_se', 'HC3_se', '_HCCM', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_cache', '_data_attr', '_get_robustcov_results', '_is_nested', '_wexog_singular_values', 'aic', 'bic', 'bse', 'centered_tss', 'compare_f_test', 'compare_lm_test', 'compare_lr_test', 'condition_number', 'conf_int', 'conf_int_el', 'cov_HC0', 'cov_HC1', 'cov_HC2', 'cov_HC3', 'cov_kwds', 'cov_params', 'cov_type', 'df_model', 'df_resid', 'eigenvals', 'el_test', 'ess', 'f_pvalue', 'f_test', 'fittedvalues', 'fvalue', 'get_influence', 'get_prediction', 'get_robustcov_results', 'initialize', 'k_constant', 'llf', 'load', 'model', 'mse_model', 'mse_resid', 'mse_total', 'nobs', 'normalized_cov_params', 'outlier_test', 'params', 'predict', 'pvalues', 'remove_data', 'resid', 'resid_pearson', 'rsquared', 'rsquared_adj', 'save', 'scale', 'ssr', 'summary', 'summary2', 't_test', 'tvalues', 'uncentered_tss', 'use_t', 'wald_test', 'wald_test_terms', 'wresid']
```

I want to understand the output of `print(dir(reg1))` and `print(dir(reg1.fit()))`. Where I can get the document of these components and examples of these pieces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Man, that is simple "googling" / reading the doc page. What is maybe confusing is the use of `statsmodels.formula.api`. This is to provide the possibility of [entering R-style formulas](http://www.statsmodels.org/stable/example_formulas.html).

The Docs of statsmodels are located here: [StatsModels Index Page](http://www.statsmodels.org/stable/index.html). Scroll down until you reach "Table of Contents". There click on [Linear Regression](http://www.statsmodels.org/stable/regression.html). Scrolling down to `Module Reference` there are links to `Model Classes` and `Result Classes`.

The correct model class is already pointed out by [@Bill Bell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/131187/bill-bell): it is [OLS](http://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLS.html#statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLS). Below `methods`, you can find the link to the documentation of `fit`, where it states that `fit` returns a `RegressionResults` object.

The [RegressionResults doc page](http://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.RegressionResults.html#statsmodels.regression.linear_model.RegressionResults) explains the attributes you are interested in.

Note that:

- attributes starting/ending in double underscore `__`, e.g. `__class__` etc. are [Python special attributes](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=special%20attributes).
- you can get help inside the Python interpreter by appending `?`, e.g. by typing `reg1?` (much like in `R` where you pre-pend the `?`)

Comment: Thanks @Tw UxTLi51Nus for very useful answer. Would highly appreciate if point out where to get pdf format of statsmodels documentation. Thanks

Comment: @MYaseen208 Sorry could not find any. There is an [open issue for it](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/1033). If what you really want is "locally available docs", you could build the docs on your machine. For that see [here](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/tree/master/docs)

Answer (score 1):

dir() is used to list all the attributes, methods and variables in a module just like in R as library(lme4)
methods(class = "merMod")
You can also try reg1.**dict**

Comment: use reg1.__dict__

Answer (score 1):

Some points to know about Python.

1. Python have built-in offline documentation in python try command in python interpreter `help`

   ```
   >>> help(dir)
   >>> help(help)
   ```
2. If you want to see online, you can visit [pydocs](https://docs.python.org/2/) for generic help. And for package specific help, visit [pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi) (Python package index)
3. Now specific to your problem. help for [statsmodels](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/statsmodels/0.8.0). which redirects to [Homepage](http://www.statsmodels.org/stable/)
4. Finally, here is a page which may interest you: [Fitting models using R-style formulas](http://www.statsmodels.org/stable/example_formulas.html?highlight=formula#fitting-models-using-r-style-formulas).

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> reg1.__module__
'statsmodels.regression.linear_model'
```

Googling for this gave me the page, http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLS.html, which includes a link to `fit`.

I don't know that this has everything you need. I hope it's a leg up.